# How to add dependency SVN project in my Podspec

Tags: svn, cocoapods, podspec

Ex:

```
Project1 (SVN)    
|------Project2 (SVN)    
|-----------Project3 (SVN)
```

When i Pod "URL to Project 2" from Project1, It creates pod for Project2 not created for Porject3. But Project2 is dependent on Project3.

How to specify the SVN repo/path for Project3 in Project2.podspec. Thanks in advance.

Project2.podspec Looks like:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name = ‘Project2’
s.version = '0.0.1'
s.summary = ''
s.homepage = ‘svn url’
s.authors = ‘authr’
s.source = { :svn => ‘SVN url to Project2’ }
s.source_files = '*/.{h,m}'

pch_AF = <<-EOS
#ifndef TARGET_OS_IOS
#define TARGET_OS_IOS TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#endif
#ifndef TARGET_OS_WATCH
#define TARGET_OS_WATCH 0
#endif
#ifndef TARGET_OS_TV
#define TARGET_OS_TV 0
#endif
EOS
s.prefix_header_contents = pch_AF
s.ios.deployment_target = '7.0'
s.osx.deployment_target = '10.9'
s.watchos.deployment_target = '2.0'
s.tvos.deployment_target = '9.0'

s.dependency 'Project3'

s.dependency 'AFNetworking'
s.dependency 'Mantle'
s.dependency 'XMLDictionary'
end
```

I know we can't add path for dependency. Is there any other way for the below line.

s.dependency 'Project3'